# How to soft wrap line in Github Gist

Tags: github, gist

I have a long string that I want to embed in my blog using Github Gist. I want to enable line-wrap for it, so that readers don't have to scroll right to view the entire string. Even after clicking the 'soft-wrap' option while editing, the final gist is not wrapped.

While editing (Soft-wrap enabled):

[image]

After saving (No line-wrap):

[image]
How can I fix this?

Comment: I am seeing the other way around. While editing i chose "no wrap". But after saving, it is doing "soft wrap". I do not want it to wrap. How do i ensure that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Github doesn't soft wrap any of the code files, including txt files. Wrapping is only applied to [prose documents](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/rendering-differences-in-prose-documents), such as *markdown* and *rst* documents.

The solution to your problem would be to rename gist from `sample_text.py` to `sample_text.md` and apply `Soft wrap`. That would produce desired effect you want to achieve.

Read [this](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Text-wrapping-in-txt-file-preview/td-p/40004) conversation on Github community for more context.

Comment: Thanks! changing it to markdown format worked. I did had to handle the HTML tags in the string, but the main problem got solved.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you @Amita .

Comment: I am seeing the other way around. While editing i chose "no wrap". But after saving, it is doing "soft wrap". I do not want it to wrap. How do i ensure that? –